# Website freezes on load for a couple of seconds

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I'm working on a Wordpress-powered website (hasn't gone live yet). Most of the time when I load the home page it's fine. Sometimes, however, it freezes for a second on load, before continuing as normal. How do I debug this issue?

Comment: Is the website Javascript heavy? Is your computer slow in general? You could be running World of Warcraft in the background when the page freezes for all we know. Upload your website so we can replicate the problem and help you if.

Comment: I think you are right though, this is definatly WoW's fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would profile your php performance with:

- [xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) using external tools like cachegrind

Next I would also do some base tests with:

- [Google Page Speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/).
- [Yahoo! YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/)

Comment: +1, and Firebug is also wonderful when profiling the website speed, with its addon: HttpFox

Comment: @Mao O man I forget to mention firebug, but you need it to use Yslow and I also believe google page speed! +thanks for +1

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing it on a server or locally?

I've encountered this while developing on a local server, and it's the database access lag usually.

Comment: The page wouldn't **freeze** because of database lag, rather it would load slower.. **freezing** to me indicates that the whole browser becomes non-responsive.

Comment: I'm assuming freezing means it takes some extra time for the request to be processed. Server side, not client side.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has a developer tool that lets you profile the page and see how much time the browser spends on different things. Its located under developer tools and is called timelines.
I think firebug for firefox can do the same but I have never used that.

Answer (score 0):

Big external resources that require a reflow may block content. Look for complex javascripts and embedded fonts in addition to your general performance analysis.